# Typesetting help

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I have a rather simple question that has me flummoxed.

Let's say I have two matrices:

```
m1 = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}};
m2 = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}};
```

I am looking to typeset `m1 ± m2` similar to:

```
Text@TableForm[m1 + "\[PlusMinus]" m2 ]
```

- Works for the most part, but I want to remove the + sign from the output
- I also want to control the text sizes for the `m1` and `m2` independently so that the `a1`, `a2` etc appear in a larger text and `u1`, `v1` appear in a smaller text

I tried:

```
Text@TableForm[m1 + "\[PlusMinus]" m2 ] /. "+" -> "x"
```

But that does not seem to work. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Something like `Text@TableForm@MapThread[PlusMinus, {{m1}, {m2}}, 3]`?

Comment: That works... I need a little more flexibility... in terms of text size for matrices... I'll add color to the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Grid[
 MapThread[PlusMinus, {m1, m2}, 2],
 BaseStyle -> 15, 
 ItemStyle -> {{Red, Blue}, {}, {1, 1} -> {18, Bold}}]
```

> [image]

```
DisplayForm@RowBox[{"(", #, ")"}] & [%]
```

> [image]

---

#### Edit

```
m1 = Map[Style[#, 18, Bold] &, {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}, {2}];
m2 = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}};

Grid@MapThread[PlusMinus, {m1, m2}, 2]
```

> [image]

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I wanted to typeset it such that a1, a2 b1,b2 are in large type and u1, U2, v1,v2 are in small type

Comment: @Pam Be careful next time :) is this ok? :)

Comment: Wonderful... Thanks Kuba!